# Ad for Network Engineering is broken in the sidebar of another Stack

Tags: support, bug, design

I spotted what looks like a broken ad for Network Engineering in the sidebar of Science-Fiction and Fantasy:

[image]

If I inspect the underlying HTML, this is what I find:

```
<div id="SE20-ad-container" style="height: 250px; width: 220px;">
<style>
#launched-ad { width: 220px; height: 250px; overflow: hidden; background: url(//sstatic.net/stackexchange/Img/launched-ads/ne-ad.png) no-repeat bottom center; }
#launched-ad-link { display: block; width: 220px; height: 250px; line-height: 1.2; color: #97e5f1 !important; font-family: "Lucida Console","DejaVu Sans Mono","Bitstream Vera Sans Mono","Courier New",Courier,Consolas,"Andale Mono WT","AndaleMono","Lucida Sans Typewriter",monospace; font-size: 18px; line-height: 26px; text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff; text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer; }
#launched-ad-inner { width: 190px; margin: 15px 15px 0 15px;}
</style>
<a id="launched-ad-link" href="http://engine.adzerk.net/r?e=eyJhdiI6NDE0LCJhdCI6MTcsImJ0IjowLCJjbSI6MTE2MSwiY2giOjExOTgsImNrIjp7fSwiY3IiOjEyNDkxMzAsImRpIjoiM2Y2MGY2ZjVkM2NjNDZmN2EyZjNmNmEzMmVhNzUzMzciLCJkbSI6MSwiZmMiOjEzMzc0MzIsImZsIjozMzM1LCJpcCI6Ijg1LjEzMy45Ny4xMjkiLCJrdyI6InN0YXItd2Fycyx4LWhvc3Qtc2NpZmkuc3RhY2tleGNoYW5nZS5jb20iLCJudyI6MjIsInBjIjowLCJlYyI6MCwicHIiOjE3NTYsInJ0IjoxLCJzdCI6MTIwNTcsInVrIjoidWUxLTdlYTNlNjA3ZTdiZDQ0M2JiZmU0YmJiYzk5YmY5NDJlIiwiem4iOjc2LCJ0cyI6MTQ1MDE3MzE4NzQzNCwiYmYiOnRydWUsInBuIjoiYWRjbTIiLCJ1ciI6bnVsbH0&amp;s=fRcI-wF8fHKq_LS26LZEnJ6QXRY&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fnetworkengineering.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F25222%2Fpacket-forwarding-decision-taken-by-router%3Futm_medium%3Dad%26utm_source%3Dhttp-scifi-stackexchange-com%26utm_campaign%3Dnetworkengineering.stackexchange.com-promo%26utm_content%3D25222">
    <div id="launched-ad">
        <div id="launched-ad-inner">packet forwarding decision taken by router</div>
    </div>
</a>
</div>
```

I also see a console error that tells me http://sstatic.net/stackexchange/Img/launched-ads/ne-ad.png is 404'ing -- this is supposed to be the background image -- and indeed, I can't reach it in my browser.

This seems like a bug.

(I'm not sure if Meta.NE is the best place to post this, but I couldn't think of anywhere better.)